# Click link, close div, open other with animation

Tags: jquery, show-hide

**Situation now:**
4 navigation links, click on it opens contentfield with animation.

**Problem:**
it is possible to open all contentfields while it should be one at the time.

**Solution?:**
when click on a navigation link, close all contentfields, open just one.

```
This is the script which works, (the overlay is useless):
```

[Click Here for JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8y7Sr/126/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(function() {
    $('.activator').each(function(){
        $(this).click(function(){
            showHideAnimation(clickedObj);
        });
    });
}

function showHideAnimation(clickedObj)
{
    $('.activator').each(function(){
        if($(this).id == clickedObj.id) {
            $(this).fadeIn('fast',function(){
                $(this).animate({'bottom':'0px'},800);
            });
        } else {
            $(this).animate({'bottom':'-600px'},800,function(){
                $(this).fadeOut('fast');
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Please try this if it doesn't work properly then replace **$(this)** with only **this**